# Using the mv command with multiple wild cards

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm still relatively new to Linux, so take it easy on a noob, eh?

I have scripts set up to move media files to a specific directory based on its name. I used a wildcard to accomplish this, but I need to make it more specific so that it only moves exactly what I want.

Example: `mv /home/user/Downloads/*Horror* /home/user/Downloads/transmission/completed/Series/AHS/`

I need to know if it's possible to include multiple wildcards to a single move command. In the preceeding example, I want the script to move all of the American Horror Story episodes to the AHS directory. The script works, but if I download anything else with the word 'horror' in it, that file will be moved as well.

Is what I'm asking possible, or is there a different method all together that I should be using?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Your command moves all files with "Horror" as part of the name and will not affect files with "horror", because Unix file names are case-sensitive. If you want to move both, then use `*[hH]orror*` or `{*Horror*,*horror*}` in the name part.

Comment: As @AFH said, isn't clear what you want.  What's multiple wildcards? It may help to remember that `mv` never sees wildcards, the shell interprets them.  What's the command line you want `mv` to see?  Also, check up on extglob, it may help you. [Here's](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) a decent explanation of various globbing tools in bash. Wouldn't mv .../American\ Horror* ..../destdir do what you want?

Comment: Maybe bringing up the wildcard wasn't necessary. I want to be able to move the file based on 2 different words. Instead of only moving files with the name horror, I would like to be able to move anything with the words American AND Horror, not American OR Horror. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a wild card like `*American*Horror*`.  You can also have additional wildcards in the source path such as `/usr/home/D*/*American*Horror*`.  Depending what is in your downloads directory a simple patter like `*A*H*` may match the desired files.

You may be able to use pattern matching such as `*[aA]merican*[hH]orror*`.

I generally either echo the command by prefixing it with `echo`, or use `ls` list files matching the pattern before running the actual command.  This gives an opportunity to tune the pattern before committing to action.